# jquery selector inside a table with multiple div's

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i am trying to reach a value in my code which is in a loop through jquery selector but i cannot figure it out because i am still a noob in jquery selector:

```
  <tr >
    <td class="qtip" title="asjdasd">
        <?php
        foreach ($this->titles as $title) {
        ?>

            <div class="title" style="font-weight: bold" >
            <?php echo $title['chapter_name']; ?>
        </div>
        <?php foreach ($title['videotitle'] as $video) {
        ?>


                <div class="title">
                    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenid" value="<?php echo $video['id'] ?>">
            <?php echo $video['video_title']; ?>
            </div>
            <div>
            <?php echo date('h:i:s', $video['video_time']) ?>
            </div>

            <div><?php echo $video['date_created'] ?></div>
        <?php if (isset($this->Videos['user_id'])) {
        ?>
        <?php if (isset($video['file_path'])) {
        ?>
                        <div> <a href="<?php echo $video['file_path']; ?>" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/white_folder.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <?php } else {
        ?>
                        <div> <a href="#" target="_blank"></a></div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } else {
        ?>
                    <div>  <a href="/auth/login" target="_blank"> <img src="/images/white_folder.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
        <?php } ?>
    <!--                    <div> <a href="/mediaplayer/player.swf?width=700&height=500&file=<? //php echo $video['video_path'];                                        ?>&image=<? //php echo str_replace('.flv', '.jpg', str_replace('/flv/', '/thumb/', $video['video_path']))                                        ?>&skin=<? //php echo URL_ADDRESS                                        ?>/mediaplayer/carbon/carbon.xml" rel="shadowbox" title="<? //php echo $video['video_title']                                        ?>" ><img src="/images/white_vid.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>-->

                <div class="jwbox">
                    <img width="21" height="27" alt="" title="" src="/images/white_vid.jpg"/>
                    <div class="jwbox_hidden">
                        <div  class="jwbox_content">
                    <?php
                    echo $video['vid_code'];
                    ?>
```

i want to reach to this Hidden value and get its value:

```
                    <input type="hidden" id="videoid" value="<?php echo $video['videoid'] ?>">

                    <script type='text/javascript'>

                        var timerinterval
                        jwplayer('player2').onPlay(function() {
                            timerinterval=setInterval('timer()',1000)});
                        jwplayer('player2').onPause(function() {
                            stopTimer()});
                        jwplayer('player2').onComplete(function(){
                            stopTimer()});


                    </script>
                    <p><?php echo $video['video_title'] ?></p>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">  <p  id ="fav" font-color="green">add to favourite  </p></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </di
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get ahold of the value in:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenid" value="<?php echo $video['id'] ?>">
```

use

```
$("input#hiddenid").val();
```

Since you are new note the following things:

ID's must allways be unique and are selected using

```
$("#idName")
```

Class's can be groups of tags selected using

```
$(".className")
```

to select all img elements use $

```
$("img")
```

to select an exact element with tag > classname > id

```
$("img.className#id")
```

Comment: but it is in a loop i want it to get me the hiddenid which will be clicked by its parent

Comment: I cannot think of a single scenario where you would use the last example. The id selector is by far and away the fastest selector available. Essentially the img.className part is redundant and would slow down the selector dramatically.

Comment: @haider I am a little confused, if you place a element on the page with a id set and you use $('#findID') to select that element, there can only be that 1 element with that 1 id on the WHOLE document? like highlander said... "There can be only one!"

Comment: @James South , Sure I know what you mean its only to inform someone of a valid way to select something!

Comment: Yeah... I just wanted to make sure he doesn't get confused. Nice Highlander reference!

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
   $('#hiddenid').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you define an ID for it, it is presumably (at least it should be), the only element with that ID, and as such you can get it simply by using `$("#videoid")` and its value with `$("#videoid").val()`

Answer (score 0):

`$(".jwbox_hidden").text();` would probably give you the content of that div using the class selector.

You should however, consider your usage. Perhaps use a hidden input with a value set in your php instead. If you are using elements to hold hidden data, try to use id's rather  than classes since you want to query only one instance of that element on your page.

e.g

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $video['vid_code']; ?>" id="jwbox_hidden" />
```

you could then simply query it using `$("#jwbox_hidden").val();` using the id selector.

More information on selector is [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) It's actually quite easy once you get the hang of it.